# Delay Queue for amount of time per session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'd like to create a system that 'appends' mails to each other.

Situation: Everytime an entity is changed I'd like to send a mail to subscribers of that entity.

But when the entity is changed 10 times on a small time (like 5 / 10 minutes) the subscribers don't need to be spammed with emails.

So I was thinking of creating a 'Queue'. And to be more precise I was thinking about using the *Azure Servicebus*.

After searching some of the documentation. I found two interesting properties.

- SessionId => Would be the entity of the Id
- BatchFlushInterval (Client-side batching)

'If the client sends additional messages during this time period, it transmits the messages in a single batch'

This sounded perfect.
In this way I recieve all the 'changes of the entity' in a single batch. And could construct a single e-mail to send.

But I don't seem to find this option anymore in the new ["Azure Service Bus NuGet"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet).

Now that I searched for alternatives, I have a feeling this is not a 'normal' practice.

Does someone have some experience in this field?
I would like to avoid having to use a cron job. But if this is the best solution please let me know.

I know this a really broad question and more a 'need for information'. So commenting with links can already make me real happy.

Thanks in advance
Brecht

Comment: I have not used this delayed batching property of ASB or the nuget package your referenced. I am using standard https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/ and BatchFlushInterval property is available there, for example as a setting when instantiating messaging factory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think `Message Sessions` or `BatchFlushInterval` is the approach to take here. What you're looking for is to buffer messages to create a single notification rather than multiple ones. I'd personally go with [receiving a batch](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/d88ae6a6fd597c8274e6b8112aad4499f5eda74c/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Core/IMessageReceiver.cs#L56) from the Azure Service Bus and process the batch to "append" notifications.